# Spring Kafka Consumer Unable to Rejoin after LeaveGroup Request

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are using Spring Kafka in Production under heavy load.
We have used @KafkaListener annotations and created those listeners as part of Spring Boot Services.

Very frequently these consumers send LeaveGroup requests to the coordinator and then the consumers hang/stuck indefinitely without any log or error. The only option we are left in that case is to redeploy that particular instance.

This is the series of logs that we see:

```
Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
This member will leave the group because consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
Member consumer-1-0d0b333d-9e5b-4038-ac3f-e5d59c4e9d19 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator 172.25.128.233:9092 (id: 2147483560 rack: null)
```

Additional information:
We are using below Kafka Configs:

- Batch Size: 10
- Max Poll Interval: 12 mins
- Heart Beat: 8 seconds
- Max Partition Size: 10 MB
- Session Timeout: 25 seconds
- Request Timeout: 20 mins

Basically, we want to know once the Consumer leaves the group, why it is not sending the Join Request again?

Comment: Could this be related to the issue reported here https://github.com/aio-libs/aiokafka/issues/625?

Comment: Thanks @Mustafa, its a similar issue, but not exactly same, I am guessing something wrong with how we are using spring-kafka library

Comment: i'm having very similar issue

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that the retry suspends the consumer thread (if a BackOffPolicy is used). There are no calls to Consumer.poll() during the retries. Kafka has two properties to determine consumer health. The session.timeout.ms is used to determine if the consumer is active. Since kafka-clients version 0.10.1.0, heartbeats are sent on a background thread, so a slow consumer no longer affects that. max.poll.interval.ms (default: five minutes) is used to determine if a consumer appears to be hung (taking too long to process records from the last poll). If the time between poll() calls exceeds this, the broker revokes the assigned partitions and performs a rebalance. For lengthy retry sequences, with back off, this can easily happen.

Since version 2.1.3, you can avoid this problem by using stateful retry in conjunction with a SeekToCurrentErrorHandler. In this case, each delivery attempt throws the exception back to the container, the error handler re-seeks the unprocessed offsets, and the same message is redelivered by the next poll(). This avoids the problem of exceeding the max.poll.interval.ms property (as long as an individual delay between attempts does not exceed it). So, when you use an ExponentialBackOffPolicy, you must ensure that the maxInterval is less than the max.poll.interval.ms property. To enable stateful retry, you can use the RetryingMessageListenerAdapter constructor that takes a stateful boolean argument (set it to true). When you configure the listener container factory (for @KafkaListener), set the factory’s statefulRetry property to true.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#stateful-retry

Comment: Thanks for replying, I think this applies when there is an exception in Listener and Kafka is retrying, the issue I have mentioned is that when a group rebalances and consumer leaves the group then why spring does not connect it again with the kafka coordinator

Comment: @DhawalKapil We are also observing something similar with spring-kafka. How did you resolve this?

Comment: @tuk you will have to try a couple of things - reducing batch size, increasing session and request timeout and also figure out the issue why the consumer is not able to acknowledge the message on time

Comment: What message you are referring to about consumer acknowledgement?